# Why is my mouse cursor coordinates suddenly scaled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, direct2d

At the beginning, sorry about my English.

I'm now learning how to build a MFC application in visual studio 2015. I'm using Direct2D to draw lines in a window.

When left button is down, my OnLbuttonDown() function is called:

```
void CMyProjectNameView::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    startPoint = point;   // start point of the line, a gloable variable.
    pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
    CView::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

When left button is up, my OnLButtonUp() function is called:

```
void CMyProjectNameView::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    pRenderTarget->DrawLine(startPoint, point, m_pbrush, 1.0f); // draw the line
    pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    CView::OnLButtonUp(nFlags, point);
}
```

So it will draw a line in the window when I drag my mouse, and it works fine yesterday.

The problem is when I run it today,  it suddenly become abnormal. The start point coordinates and end point coordinates is two times bigger than before. So When I draw the line, the line shows on the bottom right position compared to the position it supposed to be.

For instance, if I draw a line from (100,100) to (500,500), a line start from (100,100) to (500,500) will appear on screen, but when I click left button of my mouse at (100,100), move it to (500,500) and release left button, a line from (200,200) to (1000,1000) will be drawn.

```
OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
```

So basically, these two point above is scaled before they are passed in. Do I accidentally change any configurations? Is there any way to fix this?  I am sure I didn't change my code.

Comment: Have you tried calling `SetTransform()`

Comment: I don't about Direct2D, but in GDI sometimes it happens to me to forget a conversion from device coordinates to logical coordinates or vice-versa (`CDC::DPToLP` and `CDC::LPToDP`methods). I have seen a page — http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sugarontop/20121006 — unfortunately it is not in English, that may have some info for you.

Comment: @DavidThomas I called this function when initialize, it doesn't seems like the reason of my program. Problem solved, the problem is that I didn't convert my coordinates. Thank you!

Comment: @sergiol you are right, I didn't convert my coordinates.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coordinates for `DrawLine` are in device-Independent pixels. See also [DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff684173(v=vs.85).aspx)

You have probably changed the size of client rectangle, it needs to be adjusted. Try also to resize the window and see if it gets the right coordinates.

```
CRect rc;
GetClientRect(&rc);

D2D1_SIZE_F size = pRenderTarget->GetSize();
const float x = size.width / rc.right;
const float y = size.height / rc.bottom;

D2D1_POINT_2F p1;
D2D1_POINT_2F p2;

p1.x = 100 * x;
p1.y = 100 * y;

p2.x = 500 * x;
p2.y = 500 * y;

pRenderTarget->DrawLine(p1, p2, brush);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! The link you provided explain everything! The mouse coordinates is given in physical pixels, but point coordinates are passed to DrawLine() in DIPs using Direct2D. The problem is that I am using 2 screen, the text size in my system display setting is 200% for one, and 100% for another. The application window shows up in my main display when I run my program, and I changed main display from the 100% screen to the 200% screen. That's why it suddenly went wrong. I just changed the size from 200% to 100% and restart. Problem is solved. I think I will add a scale convert function.